# How to run code after the view is initialized and a Promise returns data from db in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I think the code will speak for itself.

```
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    @ViewChild('masterCanvas') canvas: ElementRef;

    width = 800;
    height = 400;

    constructor(private canvasUriService: CanvasUriService) { }

    drawingPad: DrawingPad;
    uri: string;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // Get the canvas object from DOM
        const canvasElement: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
        canvasElement.width = this.width;
        canvasElement.height = this.height;

        const drawingPad = new DrawingPad(canvasElement, {
            // backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            // penColor: '#b29600',
        });


        drawingPad.fromDataURL(this.uri);
        this.drawingPad = drawingPad;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getURI();
    }

    getURI(): void {
        this.canvasUriService.getURISlowly().then(
            uri => this.uri = uri,
            err => console.log(err)
        );
    }
}
```

To clarify, I am trying to load a previously saved canvas (will be wrapped in a `DrawingPad` class) from Mongo. The issue is that the `DrawingPad` constructor requires a `canvas` element, which means the `View` needs to have been initialized, which is why that part of the code is inside `ngAfterViewInit()`. The problem is that the stuff in `ngAfterViewInit()` happens before the  `uri` variable is set.

Is there a way for me to say in `ngAfterViewInit()`, "Wait...as soon as the `uri` variable is set, then initialize the `DrawingPad`, etc..."

I apologize in advance for not using correct terminology; I am a mathematician, and web development is brand new to me.

**EDIT**: I just read about `await`. Is this something that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two asynchronous functions and want to work with the results of both once they are available.

You could call one function after the other, making them sequential:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.canvasUriService.getURISlowly().then((uri) => {
    // Do stuff with uri
  });
}
```

This removes the parallelization however. If both are fairly slow, you might want to keep them async. 
Alternatively, both async functions store their result and call a third function which only executes if both results are there:

```
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild('masterCanvas') canvas: ElementRef;
  private uri: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.draw();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.canvasUriService.getURISlowly().then((uri) => {
      this.uri = uri;
      this.draw();
    });
  }

  private draw() {
    if (this.canvas && this.uri) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The last approach seems natural. Thanks!